# Where is the IConfiguration.Get method in ASP.NET 6 (vnext) after update to beta6?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core-mvc

For the moment almost all blog posts covering configuration with the new ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 using json for config is using something like this:

```
var token = configuration.Get<string>("AppData:CompanyName");
```

For example this question: [How to read AppSettings values from Config.json in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-config-json-in-asp-net-vnext)

But since 6 august this function is removed (if you're using bleeding edge releases) with almost no information on what to use instead.

For me this first occurred when switching to from `beta5` to `beta6` of `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr;**

Do it like this to get it working:

```
var companyName = Configuration["AppData:CompanyName"];
var branchName = Configuration["AppData:BranchName"];
// etc.
```

Explanation and source:

This commit removed the `Get` function:
https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/commit/ddd7c42ece30f0b7bb57a91ae7a627f2f99b9cf2

Some further comments when digging in the issue can be found here:
https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/246