# Asp.Net core how can I replace the Configuration Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, npgsql, asp.net-core-1.0

I am new to **ASP.NET Core RC2** and I was wondering how can I get some configuration settings and apply it to my method. For Instance in my `appsettings.json`I have this specific setting

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": 
        "Server=localhost;User Id=postgres;port=5432;Password=castro666;Database=dbname;"
  }
```

In my Controller every time I want to query the database I have to use this setup

```
 using (var conn = 
     new NpgsqlConnection(
         "Server=localhost;User Id=postgres;port=5432;Password=castro666;Database=dbname;"))
 {
     conn.Open();
 }
```

The obvious pitfull here is that if I want to add more to the configuration I have to change every single instance of that method. My question is how can I get the `DefaultConnection` in the `appsettings.json` so that I can do something like this

```
 using (var conn = 
     new NpgsqlConnection(
         ConfigurationManager["DefaultConnection"))
 {
     conn.Open();
 }
```

Comment: I know nothing regarding json app settings but I think this is what you're after. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-config-json-in-asp-net-vnext

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In **ASP.NET Core** there are a lot of options you can use to access the configuration. It seems like if you're interesting it accessing the `DefaultConnection` you'd be better off using the **DI** approach. In order to ensure that you can use constructor dependency injection we have to correctly configure a few things in our `Startup.cs`.

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

We have now read our configuration `JSON` from the builder and assigned it to our `Configuration` instance. Now, we'll need to configure it for dependency injection - so let's start by creating a simple *POCO* to hold the connection string.

```
public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public string DefaultConnection { get; set; }
}
```

We are implementing the ["Options Pattern"](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html?highlight=settings#using-options-and-configuration-objects) where we bind strongly-typed classes to configuration segments. Now, in `ConfigureServices` do this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Setup options with DI
    services.AddOptions();

    // Configure ConnectionStrings using config
    services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration);
}
```

Now that this is all in place, we can simply require the constructor of the class to take on the `IOptions<ConnectionStrings>` and we'll be given a materialized instance of the class containing the configuration values.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;

    public MyController(IOptions<ConnectionString> options)
    {
        _connectionStrings = options.Value;
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // Use the _connectionStrings instance now...
        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionStrings.DefaultConnection))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // Omitted for brevity...
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html?highlight=settings) is the official documentation which I always suggest as a *must read*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, I will also read the documentation now.

Comment: and it only takes these nine easy steps! :)

Answer (score 5):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` 
is available in .NET Core 2.0 after referencing NuGet package 
`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`

Comment: I'm glad they added this. Thanks for the info.