# Access appsettings.json values in controller classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, appsettings

Having trouble figuring out how to read appsettings.json values outside of the startup.cs. What I would like to do is, for instance, is in the _Layout.cshtml, add the site name from the config:

For example:

```
ViewData["SiteName"] = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SiteSettings:SiteName");
```

Or even better:

```
public class GlobalVars {
    public static string SiteName => Configuration.GetValue<string>("SiteSettings:SiteName");
}
```

Here's my code thus far:

[appsettings.json]

```
"SiteSettings": {
    "SiteName": "MySiteName"
}
```

[startup.cs]

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();

    var siteName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SiteSettings:SiteName");
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
```

Maybe I'm reading the docs wrong, but I can't seem to expose the Configuration object outside of the Startup class.

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-config-json-in-asp-net-vnext

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In your Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    }
```

then in your controller:

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    IConfiguration configuration;

    public ValuesController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works well.  Do you know of a way of referencing that statically in something like a GlobalVars.cs so I don't have to declare this at the top of each controller?

Comment: You could create a singleton and expose the Configuration property from it. Make sure it's always the same instance. Then you can use it in the Startup instead of creating a new Configuration instance there. This will make the Property available to others layers.

Comment: That's actually an abuse of IConfiguration. The controller shouldn't care about the configuration middleware. It shouldn't require it to be up and running just to pass a single setting. It's *DI* that should register and inject the settings to the controller, perhaps in the form of IOption<> objects