# Is services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration> really needed in .net core 2 API

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I accessed appsettings.json In .NET Core 2 Web API Controller simply by adding below:

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration appConfig;

        public MyController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            appConfig = configuration;
        }
    }
```

Without adding below in Startup class *ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)* after services.AddMvc();:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

Is there any flaws in my approach? In official docs for .Net Core 2 configuration section, its not mentioned to use 'AddSingleton' not even once: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

also by searching I couldn't find related content with accessing configuration!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/index?search=AddSingleton&scope=ASP.NET+Core

Links below shows *AddSingleton as if mandatory step*:

[Access appsettings.json values in controller classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359219/access-appsettings-json-values-in-controller-classes)

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dariuszporowski/tip-of-the-week-how-to-access-configuration-from-controller-in-asp-net-core-2-0/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the [official roadmap for ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap#configuration--web-host-defaults) says:

> An `IConfiguration` instance will be added to the services container by default in ASP.NET Core 2.0, so that all applications can easily retrieve configuration values via the container

So `services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>` (or similar) is already called by the framework itself.

You may see this behavior inside [`WebHostBuilder.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/a63932a492513cdeb4935661145084cad2ae5521/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L255) file or (when using the utility extension methods) inside [`HostBuilder.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/253be73b6fbc4a23b52080bd5e9d5161eb6cfe37/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/HostBuilder.cs#L179) file.

Comment: So what happens when user adding it manually beside its being set by default? it seems no warns or errors appeared!

Comment: As with any other registration in ASP.NET Core DI, the **last** registration is used whenever anyone requests that service from the `IServiceProvider`. Because, in your case, the registration is the same, nothing changes (you have now two identical registrations for the same service).

Comment: On VS2022 preview 4.1, `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(builder.Configuration);` will cause `System.StackOverflowException`. So this line should be remove.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is needed.But we have appsettings.local.json and if we do not add this in program.cs, we can not read datas from appsetting.local.json.
so In program.cs we add `ConfigureServices` statament  in `CreateWebHostBuilder` method at `program.cs`

```
var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseApplicationInsights()
                    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config))
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: AddSingleton is not accessible