# How do I read .Net Core configuration in a standard class library?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Today (Nov 11th 2016) I downloaded the new Visual Studio 2017 RC, installed .Net Core 1.1 and set up a Web Api project (*ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)*).  I then followed the instructions on [how to read app settings from a config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-config-json-in-asp-net-vnext).  This worked fine.

Then I created a new project in the same solution.  This was a *Class Library (.NET Standard)* under the *.NET Core* section.  I added a class with an interface and set it up with default dependency injection.

**Finally**, I tried to use the configuration in the class library through constructor injection.  I get this error message:

> The type or namespace name 'IOptions<>' could not be found

Here is my class in the class library:

```
public class Firebase : IDatabase
{
    public Firebase(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        //string basePath = 
    }
}
```

Here is the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddTransient<IDatabase, Firebase>();

        // Set up configuration files.
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(options));
    }
```

I tried to add

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
```

to make it compile, but the light bulb is telling me that this is an unnecessary reference.

What am I missing?  Is this not possible?  Is there a special class library for .NET Core?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working with `IOptions{T}` is the correct way in .NET Core. Visual Studio 2017 indicates there are unnecessary usings. This is a little bit confusing because Visual Studio indicates this when the pointer is on the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` using. Looking to the proposal Visual Studio makes, it doesn't remove the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` using but other usings for e.q. `System.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  It got me checking for possibly missing references.  Turns out I had referenced *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (1.1.0)*, but not *Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions (1.1.0)*.  After yet another restart of VS 2017 this finally worked!