# Acess Appconfig Data in all project asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

How do I access appconfig from anywhere in the application without using injection?

On this solution the acess is by controller:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-config-json-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: You should use the injectable options. Everything else is an anti-pattern and defeats the purpose of having first class DI support

Comment: Just curious... why don't you want to use DI?

Comment: I have some functions in the "core" application that accesses fixed data in appconfig. It's not a new application ... it's an application migration to the new version.