# Issues reading appsettings.json file C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm coming from regular .NET Web API and I have found the experience around configuration in .NET Core 2 absolutely maddening.

I have read the official documentation and a few tutorials such as [this one](http://www.coding-issues.com/2018/10/read-values-from-appsettings-json-.net-core.html), but they all see to error.

I have a Database helper class that is supposed to establish a MongoDB connection.

My configuration is rather simple

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "mongodb://localhost:27017"
  }
}
```

- I started with the .NET Core official Angular (ngx) boilerplate template
- I add the configuration as a service singleton in Startup.CS under the `ConfigureServices` section like so `services.AddSingleton(Configuration);`
- I attempt to inject the configuration into my class like so

  ```
  public class DatabaseHelper
  {
      public static string connstring { get; private set; }
      public DatabaseHelper(IConfiguration Configuration)
      {
          connstring = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnectionString"];
      }


      public static IMongoDatabase QuizDB { get; } = GetDatabase("QuizEngine");
      public static IMongoCollection<Quiz> QuizCol { get; } = GetQuizCollection();


      public static MongoClient GetConnection() {

          return new MongoClient(connstring);
      }

      public static IMongoDatabase GetDatabase(string database) {

          MongoClient conn = DatabaseHelper.GetConnection();
          return conn.GetDatabase(database);
      }

      public static IMongoCollection<Quiz> GetQuizCollection() {
          return DatabaseHelper.QuizDB.GetCollection<Quiz>("Quizzes");            
      }
  }
  ```

This compiles and builds fine with no Intellesense errors - But when I step through it in the debugger, the `connstring` is null.   I have tried playing around with the configuration names etc, but I always seem to come up empty.

I have also tried the POCO way using the example code in the below answer, but I seem to run into static field initializer issues.

[Getting value from appsettings.json in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940710/getting-value-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core)

if it helps here is the the startup class part where it sets the public value of `Configuration`

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Comment: Is it a typo that your names don't match? `DefaultConnection` vs `DefaultConnectionString`

Comment: What Chris said. Plus, you shouldn't inject `IConfiguration` into your classes. Use the options pattern or directly inject the `MongoClient`(and register it via factory method, such as `services.AddScoped<IMongoClient>(provider => new MongoClient(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

Comment: You can read more about the options pattern here: [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1). P.S. it says Options pattern in ASP.NET Core, but it can also be applied to console applications

Comment: @Chris you are correct I had a typo - However I tried changing it to something simpler (`dburi`) and it still showed as null.

Comment: @tseng  I gave it a try and I run into "an object reference is required for a non-static field, method or property

Comment: Ah, just noticed everything is static except the constructor. Are you calling these methods on an instance of your object that was instantiated by the DI container?

Comment: Ah, duh.  A constructor is useless when I use the statics.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add the configuration as a service singleton in Startup.CS under the `ConfigureServices` section like `services.AddSingleton(Configuration);`

If you separate your solution into multiple projects with use of class libraries, `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` package comes in handy for reading the values from `appsettings` files and injecting them into your configuration classes within projects.

It has 2 extensions you can use:

```
public static T Get<T>(this IConfiguration configuration);
public static IServiceCollection Configure<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, 
    IConfiguration config) where TOptions : class;
```

your configuration file `appsetting.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MongoDBConnection": "mongodb://localhost:27017"
  }
}
```

add code for `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs` file

```
  services.Configure<MongoDBconfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
  services.AddSingleton<DatabaseHelper>();
```

your `DBhelper.cs`

```
    public class MongoDBconfig
    {
        public string MongoDBConnection { get; set; }
    }

    public class DatabaseHelper
    {
        public static string connstring { get; private set; }
        public DatabaseHelper(IOptions<MongoDBconfig> Configuration)
        {
            connstring = Configuration.Value.MongoDBConnection;
        }


        public static IMongoDatabase QuizDB { get; } = GetDatabase("QuizEngine");
        public static IMongoCollection<Quiz> QuizCol { get; } = GetQuizCollection();


        public static MongoClient GetConnection()
        {

            return new MongoClient(connstring);
        }

        public static IMongoDatabase GetDatabase(string database)
        {

            MongoClient conn = DatabaseHelper.GetConnection();
            return conn.GetDatabase(database);
        }

        public static IMongoCollection<Quiz> GetQuizCollection()
        {
            return DatabaseHelper.QuizDB.GetCollection<Quiz>("Quizzes");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way using this extension method [GetConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationExtensions_GetConnectionString_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_String_)

```
public DatabaseHelper(IConfiguration Configuration)
{
    connstring = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
}
```

Comment: Came back as null :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public DatabaseHelper(IConfiguration Configuration)
{
   string test = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["DefaultConnection"];
   Console.WriteLine(test);

}
```

Check if this able to extract the value in your appsettings.json