# Read Constants from appsettings.json in a .Net Core Class Library

Tags: .net-core, appsettings

I need to get values from appsettings.json file in a .Net Core (2.0) class library. There are lots of solutions for ASP.Net but not for .Net Core. My appsettings.json like below;

```
{
   {

    "serviceAccountEmail": "******@dotnet****.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "Certificate": "*********.p12",
    "secret": "*********",
    "ImpersonatedUser": "*********@*********.com",
    "GoogleApplicationName": "********"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set that up in your `Startup` configuration

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Startup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var value = _config["key"];
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IConfiguration config)
    {
        var value = config["key"];
    }
}
```

MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#access-configuration-during-startup

**Separation of Concerns**

If you separate your solution into multiple projects with use of class libraries, **Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions** package comes in handy for reading the values from `appsettings` files and injecting them into your configuration classes within projects.

It has 2 extensions you can use:

```
public static T Get<T>(this IConfiguration configuration);
public static IServiceCollection Configure<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, 
    IConfiguration config) where TOptions : class;
```

#### Example:

I put all security related services using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` into its own project called `DL.SO.Services.Security`.

**Security settings in appsettings.json**

I define configurations, called "AppIdentitySettings", for identity options I want to set up in `ASP.NET Core Identity` framework in my web/start-up project.

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        ...
    },
    "AppIdentitySettings": {
        "User": {
            "RequireUniqueEmail": true
        },
        "Password": {
            "RequiredLength": 6,
            "RequireLowercase": true,
            "RequireUppercase": true,
            "RequireDigit": true,
            "RequireNonAlphanumeric": true
        },
        "Lockout": {
            "AllowedForNewUsers": true,
            "DefaultLockoutTimeSpanInMins": 30,
            "MaxFailedAccessAttempts": 5
        }
    },
    "Recaptcha": {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

**Configuration classes**

Then you need to define configuration classes, which are just POCOs, to represent your configuration structure in `appsettings.json`. The name of the configuration class doesn't have to match the section name you define in the `appsettings.json`, but rather the names of the properties need to match.

```
namespace DL.SO.Services.Security
{
    public class AppIdentitySettings
    {
        public UserSettings User { get; set; }
        public PasswordSettings Password { get; set; }
        public LockoutSettings Lockout { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserSettings
    {
        public bool RequireUniqueEmail { get; set; }
    }

    public class PasswordSettings
    {
        public int RequiredLength { get; set; }
        public bool RequireLowercase { get; set; }
        public bool RequireUppercase { get; set; }
        public bool RequireDigit { get; set; }
        public bool RequireNonAlphanumeric { get; set; }
    }

    public class LockoutSettings
    {
        public bool AllowedForNewUsers { get; set; }
        public int DefaultLockoutTimeSpanInMins { get; set; }
        public int MaxFailedAccessAttempts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Above is from and in more detail:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46940811/2343826

Comment: In this solution, values are called from a main method, in my case the values should be read from a class library- means there is no main method.

Comment: @AshleyCam revised in the answer.

Comment: Hi, In my scenario, I have different project in on solution and my appsetting.json is in MVC project of the solution and rest at class library project. In this can how can I access the configuration setting using DI for the same appsetting.json throughout the project.
MVC code access my class library by creating object like ClassName obj= new ClassName(). Here I get compile time error for all the obvious reason as I define a parameterized constructor for the class to access Configuration setting. Is there any way I can achieve this as have tried lots of solutions