# How to get values from Appsettings.json to be used in Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings

I know that there's a way to get Configuration sections by adding it to the services like so:

```
Configuration.GetSection("SectionName")
```

And then using dependency injection, I can use that configuration in my controllers. I also know that there's a way to extract connectionstrings from appsettings.json into the startup.cs.

However, what I want is to use a non-connectionstring value from my appsettings.json to be used in my startup.cs. I have a group in my policy that I want to be configurable in the appsettings.json.

In my appsettings.json, there is a config section that looks like this:

```
"ConfigurableGroupName": "Administrators",
```

And my policy is being set like the following:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("PolicyName", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupRequirement("ConfigurableGroupName") ));
        });
```

How do I replace "ConfigurableGroupName" with the value that I have in my appsettings.json? Is there a way to do this or a better way to do this?

EDIT: This is different because I'm trying to use appsettings values that are not connectionstrings in Startup.cs. Not in the controller or anywhere else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31453663/6027876

Comment: In aspnetcore2.1 the ctor of `Startup` gets the `IConfiguration` as argument `public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)`

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there isn't a way to use the appsettings values in the startup.cs itself or turn it into a raw string unless it's a connectionstring.

Comment: @Frosteeze you are mistaken. you can extract anything from the settings. not just the connection string.

Comment: @Frosteeze perhaps if you clarify what it is you are actually trying to extract in a [mcve] we might be able to help. Right now you have not provided enough details.

Comment: Rechecking the dupe target, this is in fact a duplicate as there are multiple answers there that should allow you to achieve what you require.

Comment: `var groupName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConfigurableGroupName");` and you pass that to your `new GroupRequirement(groupName);`

Comment: @Nkosi Ok I see that this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54060567/3866585 might help. The other comment linked to the first top voted answer, which was not helpful.

Comment: @Nkosi that answer worked as well, thank you!