# Error CS1503 - Cannot convert from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection to System.Action<>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, c#-4.0, .net-core

I am getting an error:

**Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to 'System.Action<>**

When I am using Configure with Bind(), it is working.

```
var bandConfig = new BandSettings();
Configuration.GetSection("BandSettings").Bind(bandConfig );
```

But with the below code, I am getting the above error.

I tried many solutions suggested in blogs and other forums, 
For example - [Getting value from appsettings.json in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940710/getting-value-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core)

but still the same error. Am I missing anything??

I have below things in place:
**appsettings.json**

```
"BandSettings":{ 
"UserID": "aTestUserID", 
"Password" : "aTestPassword" 
}
```

**BandSettings.cs**

```
public class BandWidthSettings
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string ApiToken { get; set; }
}
```

**TestHelper.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static IConfiguration GetTestConfiguration()
         => new ConfigurationBuilder()
                       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                       .Build();

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public TestHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    var config = new BandSettings();
    var bandSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("BandSettings");
    services.Configure<BandSettings>(bandSettingsSection);  //Error is getting on this line - bandSettingsSection
}
```

Comment: Isn't it: `services.Configure<BandSettings>(o => bandSettingsSection.Bind(o));`

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thank you for your comment. It works with Bind().  But I don't want to use Bind() with it.

Comment: OK, but you still have to deal with `Configure` looking for an action (`o => SomeVoidMethod()`) and not a configuration section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public TestHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Configure section binding  
            services.Configure<BandSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(BandSettings.SECTION));
        }
```

Comment: It's needed add Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions from NuGet.
You can make it easier writing down OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions in your code and wait for VS suggest you.

Answer (score 191):

Add NuGet package [**Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/) to get the extension method where

```cs
services.Configure<BandSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("BandSettings"));
```

will work.

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/18833

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` nuget package matters!!

Comment: Extension methods are the crappiest idea, when there is no way to tell where a method is provided. The documentation hardly ever helps.

Comment: How-to use it in MSTest project?

Answer (score 5):

Create a POCO for the setting

```
public class MySetting
{
  public string Setting{ get; set; }
}
```

On Startup it works perfectly as it should be:

```
services.Configure<MySetting>(Configuration.GetSection("MySetting"));
```

However on my the dependecy injection add the bind as mentioned in the question comments.

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  var mySection = configuration.GetSection("MySetting");
  services.Configure<MySetting>(c => mySection .Bind(c));
}
```

Comment: `c => mySection .Bind(c)` was the missing part for me. Thank you.