# How to enable CORS in Asp.Net Core 3.0 WebAPI

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, cors, cross-domain

I want to enable CORS with Asp.Net Core 3.0 API project. This is the basic generated Asp.Net Core Api template. Everything is default from the template, except I added CORS settings from the documentation

```
public class Startup
 {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors(opt =>
        {
            var origins = Configuration
                .GetSection("AllowedHosts")
                .Get<string[]>();

            opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
                    .WithOrigins(origins)
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .Build());
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

What should I set up for getting corret CORS in .net core web api?
Allowed host is :
[image]

Comment: Seems about right to me, what's wrong with that code?

Comment: Yeah it looks correct, could you specify a bit more what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am getting exception `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:44314/api/Reservation' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` while calling it from another application

Comment: @devcrp It is working with if I change it to
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                     builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });

Comment: Can I pickup the values "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:44349" from app setting as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of precedence for `Cors` should be before adding controllers. It should be added as define in the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Follow this code:

```
public class Startup
 {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                 .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:44349")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                //.AllowCredentials());
                 );
        });

      services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
       
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();    
        app.UseRouting(); 
        
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");   
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

As per the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-policy-options), it must be noted that:

> Specifying AllowAnyOrigin and AllowCredentials is an insecure
> configuration and can result in cross-site request forgery. The CORS
> service returns an invalid CORS response when an app is configured
> with both methods.

Comment: Can I pickup the values "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:44349" from app setting as well?

Comment: Yes, put in a comma separated string in app.settings and retrieve later.

Comment: I just put 
"AllowedHosts": [
    "http://localhost:4200"
  ],
in app setting and get like as below, but didn't work
services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                var origins = Configuration
                    .GetSection("AllowedHosts")
                    .Get<string[]>();

                opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
                        .WithOrigins(origins)
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .Build());
            });

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940710/getting-value-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core