# Can't authorize swagger through my Authorization Server using OIDC

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, openid-connect, swashbuckle, openiddict

I'm using `Swashbuckle` configured as

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v2" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("OpenId", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect,
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"{authority}connect/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri($"{authority}connect/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {
                        "openid", "openid"
                    },
                    {
                        "api", "api"
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        OpenIdConnectUrl = new Uri($"{authority}.well-known/openid-configuration"),
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "OpenId",
                },
            },
            new List<string> { "api", "openid" }
        },
    });
});
```

And after that

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "API v2");
    c.OAuthUsePkce();
    c.OAuthClientId(Configuration.GetRequiredSection("SwaggerOptions:ClientId").Value);
    c.OAuthClientSecret(Configuration.GetRequiredSection("SwaggerOptions:ClientSecret").Value);
    c.EnablePersistAuthorization();
    c.OAuthScopes("api", "openid");
});
```

I see resulting `swagger.json` seems to be correct, [as it declared at the docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/openid-connect-discovery/)

[image]

But something goes definitely wrong - I get `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing` reason for discovery request rejecting, simultaneously it returns a correct configuration with 200 ok

[image]

What have I missed?

Comment: Have you added cors policy in startup.cs? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61932251/13405106), [link_2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: @Usama, sure. For brevity, I allowed all origins, headers, methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I was able to get this to work. I was misunderstanding which part does require CORS in this case. To fix that, I added my Swagger UI host to allowed hosts on auth server side and switch CORS on there. Now, all work fine!