# Global variable for web api base URL for Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Currently, I have this working Blazor (Server Project) which have just a button which issue a Web Api GET request and it works without any issue.

This is my `ConfigureServices` method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();         
    }
```

and in my `Index.razor`

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient http;
@using Models

<button @onclick="@GetMovies">Get Movies</button>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Movie</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var movie in @Movies)
        {
        <tr><td>@movie.MovieTitle</td></tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code{
    List<Movie> Movies;

    private async Task GetMovies()
    {
        Movies = await http.GetJsonAsync<List<Movie>>("http://localhost:54124/api/Movies");
    }
}
```

How do I put `http://localhost:54124` into just one single location like global variable? Do it at `ConfigureServices` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store it in `appsettings.json`.

If you are using WASM, `appsettings.json` will be inside `wwwroot`.

And to get the value from it, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940710/getting-value-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core)  where the answer to it my change according to the version of .net core and there is more than one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

1- create a class

```
public class GlobalVariable
{
    public string Test { get; set; } = "any thing";
}
```

2- put it as singleton

```
Services.AddSingleton<GlobalVariable>();
```

now you can use it anywhere just write

```
@inject GlobalVariable _globalVariable
_globalVariable.Test
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a static parameter when combined with the Dependency injection.  You should use a non static variable, then inject the instance of GlobalVariable (using the inject mechanism) to get the instance you declared in the AddSingleton line