# How to get section from a configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to transfer data from `appsettings.json` to an instance of `MailSettings` at runtime :

Here's the model :

```cs
public class MailSettings
{
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
}
```

In `program.cs`, I try to configure the service with the following instruction:

```cs
    builder.Services.Configure<MailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));
```

But I have the following problem:

> **Compiler Error CS0120** : An object reference is required for the
> nonstatic field, method, or property
> `Configuration.GetSection(string)`

If someone has a solution ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65933664/how-to-read-section-values-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core/65933846#65933846

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
builder.Services.Configure<MailSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** **If you want to get section in program.cs**

Try

```
var settings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings").Get<MailSettings>();
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69390676/how-to-use-appsettings-json-in-asp-net-core-6-program-cs-file) to know more

Result:

in appsetings.json:

```
"MailSettings": {
    "Mail": "a@a.com",
    "DisplayName": "aa",
    "Password": "123"
  }
```

[image]

**2. If you want to get section in Controller/class**

Try

```
builder.Services.Configure<MailSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));
```

HomeController:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public MailSettings MailSettings { get; }
        public HomeController(IOptions<MailSettings> smtpConfig)
        {
            MailSettings = smtpConfig.Value;
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]