# How to access a value from appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core 6 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have created a brand new ASP.NET Core Web API project (.NET 6) from the default template provided in Visual Studio 2022. After that I added a config key in the ***appsettings.json*** file and am trying to access it inside the `controller` class, but can't.

My **appsettings.json** file is below:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ProjectName" : "VeryFunny"
}
```

The controller code is below:

```cs
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public WeatherForecastController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = _configuration["ProjectName"] // <-- I added this
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

I receive `null` instead of `VeryFunny` string in the above method, where I have added an arrow comment. I assumed that after the merging of `Startup.cs` class and `Program.cs` class in .NET 6, `IConfiguration` is easily available now, but it seems I was wrong.

**UPDATE:**

This is a bare bone project you get when you create a new ASP.NET Core Web API ***targeting .NET 6***, in Visual Studio 2022. When I create a new project targeting .NET 5, I have no issues because in that `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` are separate classes and an instance of `IConfiguration` is already injected in `Startup` class, whereas this is not the case in .NET 6. There is [an existing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940710/getting-value-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core) which asks the same question, but that question and its answers are focused on .NET implementations prior to .NET 6, for example .NET Core 2.x, .NET 5 etc. Mine is .NET 6 specific.

Comment: There's useful info on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67292524/361842 - note: in this case they'd put custom attributes under an `AppSettings` parent element; whilst your `ProjectName` sits on the root...  By convention you'd want to nest it under `AppSettings`, though it is possible to access it programmatically without that.

Comment: Please check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting value from appsettings.json in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940710/getting-value-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core)

Comment: @Manish No. I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: Have you modified codes in Program.cs?I tried with your codes ,it works well in .net 6

Comment: Same piece of code works for me without changing anything other then what you mentioned. now you tell us what you have changed in the program.cs.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to use `.GetValue<type>`, so try

```
Summary = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ProjectName");
```

You can also check detailed posts
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58432834/3559462 (shows how to get value)

https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp-net/read-values-from-appsettingsjson-in-net-core/467 (Shows binding of Model from appsettings.json)

**Update:**

I created new .NET Core 6 API project and used this code

```
  private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IConfiguration configuratio)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuratio;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ProjectName")

    })
        .ToArray();
```

It worked for me, here is the GIF image

[image]

Comment: It didn't help. I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: @user419022 Updated my answer, I tried creating new .NET Core 6 project in VS 2022 and tested output, looks ok to me.

Answer (score 7):

I figured out how to access appsettings.json from controller using IConfiguration interface inside the constructor.

below my example of code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private string ConnectionString;

        public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _config = configuration;
            ConnectionString = _config["Configurations:ConnectionString"];
            Console.WriteLine(ConnectionString);
        }
```

The connection String (in this case was the parameter inside json file) showed successfully!
my appsettings.json code:

```
"Configurations": {
    "ConnectionString": "MyDBConnectionStringExample;"
  }
```

I really recommend that you will need a separated class to handle all the database communication if it's the case, otherwise it work's well... hope it helps someone.

Comment: This was a fantastic answer.  Just what I needed.  Thanks for writing this one up. Could not figure out how to get config value in my controller.

Comment: Thank you very much for leaving your feedback, I'm glad I could help. @raddevus

Answer (score 0):

These options maybe helpful:

1. Maybe your `appsettings.json` file is not copied on the building.
   Right click on `appsettings.json` file and select properties. then `Copy to Output Directory` should be equal to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`.
2. If you have multiple appsettings like  `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Development.json`, `appsettings.Production.json`. Be sure your key(`ProjectName`) is in all of them

Comment: Nops, It didn't help. I updated my question to be more specific.