# Why does IConfiguration return null after upgrading from .Net Core 2.2 to .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, appsettings, .net-core-3.1

In .Net Core 2.2, I only had to inject `IConfiguration` in the Startup.cs constructor and then I could access values using `configuration.GetValue<string>("Foo:Bar:BazValue");`, but since upgrading to .Net Core 3.1 this is returning null.

Why is that? I read somewhere that I needed to add the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`, but that seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757189/how-to-get-value-from-appsettings-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757189/how-to-get-value-from-appsettings-json)