# How to get the child elements by specifying the child name in json settings file?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-configuration

```
"AppSettings": 
{"AzureAd":
 {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "abc.com",
"TenantId": "90836560-70ab-4caa-9e10-7e80b43d8d5a"
 }
}
```

How to get the value of a "Instance" value in the class file. I have tried  this below which doesn't work

```
 var symmetrickey = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:AzureAd:Instance").GetChildren()
                  .Select(configSection => configSection.Value);
```

where as Im getting array of node "AzureAd" when I modify like below

```
var symmetrickey = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:AzureAd").GetChildren()
                  .Select(configSection => configSection.Value);
```

But I want the "Instance"/"TenantId" value by specifically mentioning either of the text .

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. The .NET Core configuration system reads data from *any* of the configured providers and converts them to key/value pairs. It looks like the actual question is how to get a value by specifying the full path? Have you tried [GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#getvalue) ?

Comment: GetValue It didnt work @Kanavos

Comment: How did you use it? In fact, why don't you use the common way shown in the docs of loading all the settings as a single object and eg registering with DI ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read AppSettings values from .json file in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-json-file-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON for the appsetting should not start with a json key. Remove "AppSettings":

```
{
  "AzureAd":
  {
     "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
     "Domain": "abc.com",
     "TenantId": "90836560-70ab-4caa-9e10-7e80b43d8d5a"
  }
}
```

To get the value

```
 var symmetrickey = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAd:Instance").Value;
```