# Configuring services for ASP.NET core and .NET core CLT

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to use the same code and hopefully configuration to set up DI for both ASP.NET core and .net core command-line tools.

I understand how to use Startup.cs to configure services for ASP.NET core. I understand how to build a `ServiceCollection` in a command-line tool, though other than accessing it explicitly, I am not exactly sure how to use it, and I think my CLT has to manage the service collection itself (unlike ASP.NET that provides a service collection and constructor injection).

Can my web and CLT projects use the same extension method to register my services? `Startup.ConfigureServices` would pass the `ServiceCollection` and Configuration that it receives to my extension method. The CLT I can pass the `ServiceCollection` that the CLT manages, but can it get the same type of Configuration from an `appsettings.json` file?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I think that I am very close based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-a-json-file-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

In the CLT I needed some nuggets:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Cofiguration.Json
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting

private static ServiceCollection _services = new ServiceCollection();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
//TODO:                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        builder.Build();
        IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder =
            new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        ServiceProvider provider = ConfigureServices(_services, configBuilder.Build()).BuildServiceProvider(); //TODO: dispose
        _repo = provider.GetService<IRepository>();
        provider.Dispose();
```

I would probably set a property of the CLT to the provider, but then I am not sure how to ensure that it gets disposed.

Comment: It's definitely the right approach to use the app type agnostic configuration APIs as you are doing here. Regarding disposal: 1: Do not call dispose manually, it is not exception safe; use `using`, 2: your application's logical lifetime is entirely within the main method. Therefore using a field is pointless and confusing extra code. Remove the field and write `using var provider = new ConfigureServices(new ServiceCollection(), configBuilder.Build()).BuildServiceProvider();`.