# What is the best way to pass a url in a class.cs in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, http, url, httprequest

I developed a code where I do some http request. I used to hard coded the url which i used for the http calls but i want to make it more efficient. What I did is:

Updated the appsettings.json file:

```
{

    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"

        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "urls": "http://localhost:5002",
}
```

Added the urls field.

Created a field in the class where i want the url:

```
private readonly string _url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urls"];
```

Program.cs class

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5002");
                });
    }
```

In order to get the url from appsettings, and then pass the _url variable where i want to use it in the class. However for some reason im getting null value when im trying to run the program. Am I doing something wrong? and is there any better solution than that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share your startup.cs?

Comment: please add your startup.cs no your main class to check if you add  `.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);` to your configuration builder

Comment: you sure that is the content from appsettings.json and not from appsettings.Development.json?

Comment: yes i checked that

Answer (score 0):

The way the appsettings.json loads into the app builder is different then .NET Framework.
But this has been answered in another post.
See [How to read AppSettings values from a .json file in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-a-json-file-in-asp-net-core).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to avoid this problem is to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` class to retreive your data from `appsettings.json` .

Probably you will need also to inject the `Configuration` in your controller class as show below

```
private readonly IConfiguration _config;

public ConfigurationController(IConfiguration config)
{
    _config = config;
}
```

Now you can retrieve your data using the code below :

```
_config.GetValue<string>("urls");
```

Comment: can i initialize the Configuration class to pass it in contructors?

Comment: you don't need to initialize it .

Comment: @Josh sorry i just make an update my post ,please retry and check it's suppose to work.