# Accessing JSON array from appsettings in controller without Configuration C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, appsettings

I've already searched, there are similar questions, but with JSON Array in answers they are using `IConfigure` in the controller. I can use `IConfigure` only in Startup.

I have this JSON Array in `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "EmailList":{
    "EmailArray":[
      {
        "name":"John Algovich",
        "email":"John.Algovich@mail.com"
      },
      {
        "name":"Petr Algr",
        "email":"Petr.Algr@mail.com"
      },
      {
        "name":"Mathew Cena",
        "email":"Mathew.Cena@mail.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`EmailList.cs`:

```
public partial class EmailList 

{
  public List<string> EmailArray { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

There is a lot of injections in `Startup.cs`, so I used the same code for mine:

```
services.Configure<EmailList>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailList"));
```

`Controller`:

```
public class DevController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EmailList _devEmailList;
        private List<string> _emailList;

        public DevController(

            IOptions<EmailList> _devEmailList,
        {

            _devEmailList = devEmailList.Value; //This could be wrong since it's json array
            
_emailList = new List<string>();

        }
    }
```

Goal: How can I access email adresses in Controller and add it to the list?

I can't use `IConfigure` in Controller.

*I was refering to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-a-json-file-in-asp-net-core/31453663#31453663), but it originally having json without array.
Questions with Json Arrays using `IConfigure` in Controller*

Comment: I think EmailList class does not represent the correct JSON from the appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 1):

Your class definition doesn't mirror the structure of your json;

```cs
public class EmailAddress {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class EmailList {
  public List<EmailAddress> EmailArray { get; set; }
}
```

Though you could simplify both;

```cs
public class EmailList:List<EmailAddress> {}
```

```json
{
  "EmailList":[
    {
      "name":"John Algovich",
      "email":"John.Algovich@mail.com"
    },
    {
      "name":"Petr Algr",
      "email":"Petr.Algr@mail.com"
    },
    {
      "name":"Mathew Cena",
      "email":"Mathew.Cena@mail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps, but the main goal access emails and add it to the list. Do you know how can I do that?