# How to read appsettings.json in any Class with .Net core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this class that connects to my oracle database:

```
public class Conexao : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IOptions<Configuracao> _config;
    public OracleConnection ConexaoOra{ get; internal set; }
    private OracleTransaction _transacao;
    private bool _finalized;
    private bool _commited;
    private const string CONNECTION_STRING = "myConnectionString";


    public Conexao(IOptions<Configuracao> config)
    {
        _config = config;
        _finalized = false;
        _commited = false;
        ConexaoOra = new OracleConnection();
        ConexaoOra.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
        ConexaoOra.Open();
    }

  
    ~Conexao()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel level = System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
    {
        _transacao = ConexaoOra.BeginTransaction(level);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if (_transacao != null)
        {
            _transacao.Commit();
            _transacao = null;
        }
        _commited = true;
    }

}
```

This class is instantiated every time any transaction is triggered in the DAL class

sample:

```
   using ((conexao == null ? conexao = new Conexao() : conexao))
   OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand("", conexao.ConexaoOra);
   //...
```

The Json Settings File and the Connection Class are in different projects in the same solution

how to load in this line my connectionString of appSettings Json File?

```
       private const string CONNECTION_STRING = "myConnectionString";
```

Comment: Tag the question with `C#`, not `C`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read AppSettings values from a .json file in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-a-json-file-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I took the example from an old project where I used ServiceStack and it probably had some helpers to ease the procedure. With just plain .NET it seems to be more tedious, so have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-a-json-file-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: what package? show for me this "Lucene.Net.Support"

Comment: the Json Settings and the Connection Class are in different projects in the same solution