# Getting a parameter error in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

Error snippet in Visual studio:

[image: Error snippet in Visual studio]

GetConnectionString parameter error ASP.NET Core 6.0

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
> required formal parameter 'name' of
> 'ConfigurationExtensions.GetConnectionString(IConfiguration, string)'

Comment: Add ```Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions``` package to project

Comment: its not helping, still the same error
though, the error shown is about parameters of the getconnectionstring method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core 6 how to access Configuration during setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69722872/asp-net-core-6-how-to-access-configuration-during-setup)

Comment: Ok, you are right. I misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sample:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```