# Sending parameter by docker-compose does not work on appsettings in .NET6

Tags: docker-compose, .net-6.0, appsettings

I have a docker-compose with environment variables for the ConnectionString :

```
services:
  nameservice:
  ...
  environment:
    ConnectionStrings__mysqlDatabase: "Server=db;Uid=root;Pwd=password;"
```

I have on the .NET side in a console program, an AppSettings file (.NET6):

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "mysqlDatabase": "Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=password;"
  }
}
```

and my program.cs :

```
IConfiguration Config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
ConnectionStringConstant.mysqlDatabase = Config.GetConnectionString("mysqlDatabase");
```

my problem is that in docker after creating a container, it keeps the value in AppSettings (which is not good for production) and it does not take the value passed by the docker-compose file.

Can you help me?

Comment: Finally, I found the solution, I just had to add this: `.AddCommandLine(args)` on the line: `IConfiguration Config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")`

Comment: ** `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building configuration manually (without using hosting) setup for environment variables support is required:

```cs
var configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

Read more:

- [Configuration in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration#basic-example)

Comment: from where these code of block add in file , in startup or in programe.cs file ?

Comment: @SaadAwan if you have `Startup` class usually it means that you are utilizing generic hosting model, so it should do it already.