# serilog: how to write logs to 2 different sinks using ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, serilog

I am using .Net 6 Web Api application using C# and wanted to write logs only to console if `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development` and for non-dev wanted to write logs to Azure Blob Storage.

Question 1. How to use `app builder` before it's created  for code `if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())` ? or I have to use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`?

Question 2. can this be achieved without `if/else` block and within single line I can change the write context?

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
                .WriteTo.Console());
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
            .WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage());
        }
```

Comment: Q1: `builder.Environment`. Q2: Probably, but that's more of an code-style issue, e.g. not really 'on-topic' here. I would not worry about it, it is more readable the way you already wrote it.

Comment: You could add a `public static class ServiceContainerExtensions` and a `public static IServiceCollection SetupServiceCollection(this IServiceCollection services)` inside it. Call it from your Program.cs with `builder.Services.SetupServiceCollection();` if you want it cleaner.

Comment: Could you please complete code snippet for `SetupServiceCollection`?

Comment: Maybe better use the [configuration file](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--)?

Comment: @user584018 [small fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2HJ5xv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69722872/asp-net-core-6-how-to-access-configuration-during-startup/69722959#69722959) you can access the environment from the builder itself:

```cs
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
   // ...
}
```

As for "clever" one-liners not much can be done here, I recommend to stick to the if-else as more readable approach (and potentially moving the Serilog setup logic to extension method), but just for funsies - abusing ternary with the discard:

```cs
_ = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()
    ? builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc.WriteTo.Console())
    : builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc.WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage());
```

Or

```cs
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => _ = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()
        ? lc.WriteTo.Console()
        : lc.WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage());
```

But I hugely recommend considering the ability to set up the logger via [configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--).