# how to use CreateHostBuilder(args).Build(); in .NET 6

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I was using .NET 5 and I wrote this line of code in `Startup.cs`

```cs
var host= CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
host.MigrateDatabase<Program>();
host.Run();
```

but now I don't know how should I use this in .NET 6 at Program.cs

Comment: _"i wrote this line of code in startup.cs"_ - I highly doubt that you wrote this in `Startup` class.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 6 has introduced the [new minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model) for ASP.NET Core apps. In short you can summarize the changes to the following:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Here goes code from Startup.ConfigureServices

var app = builder.Build();

// Here goes code from Startup.Configure

app.Run();
```

For more details check the:

- [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 5.0 to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model) article
- [Code samples migrated to the new minimal hosting model in ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0) article
- [ASP.NET Core 6 how to access Configuration during startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69722959/2501279)

Note that the "old" [generic host model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) ([ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0) version) still exists, works and can be used (actually some templates like worker one still use it).