# What is "an alternate pipeline" in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Reading the docs for UseExceptionHandler extension method, that adds standard exception handler middleware, I see following description:

> UseExceptionHandler(IApplicationBuilder)
>
> Adds a middleware to the pipeline that will catch exceptions, log
> them, and re-execute the request in **an alternate pipeline**. The request
> will not be re-executed if the response has already started.

However I was not able to find in docs what this means exactly. What is `an alternate pipeline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In software-engineering *in general*, a "pipeline" refers to a sequence-of-events, steps, or handlers which are *composed* in advance, and which concerns the processing of *something* from start-to-finish, with the implication that, for each step, the output of a previous step is used as the input for the next step.

  - For example, a build-automation or *CI/CD pipeline* will be a predefined sequence of steps that take your project's repo, gather up its dependencies, invoke the compiler/linker/etc for whatever output targets there are, and publish the end-result, all in a single pipeline that's ideally *hands-off*.
  - Another example is [in the Unix shell](https://youtu.be/tc4ROCJYbm0?t=454): where the `stdout` output of one command is fed as the `stdin` of another, e.g. `makewords sentence | lowercase | sort | unique > output.txt`

    - This is something you'll see a lot in FP (functional-programming) scenarios, especially in FP-heavy frameworks like RxJS, [where *operators* can be chained into a pipeline](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators#piping), for example.

---

- ASP.NET Core's concept of a *pipeline* refers to the *composed* sequence of middleware handlers (and other *things*) which you assemble during `Startup` with those `UseSomething()` methods on `WebApplicationBuilder`.

  - [Prior to *ASP.NET Core 6*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69722872/asp-net-core-6-how-to-access-configuration-during-startup) this is what your `Startup.Configure()` method is for: it defines the sequence of handlers that get invoked for *every* incoming HTTP request.

    - <sub>(Don't confuse `Configure()` with `ConfigureServices()`: `Configure()` is for *configuring the pipeline*, while `ConfigureServices()` is for *configuring the DI system*: they're very distinct things.</sub>
    - If you're alarmed by this talk of configuring handlers that run for *every request* because it sounds wasteful or redundant - don't worry: ASP.NET Core has always supported *branching* the request pipeline, so *not every* middleware handler is necessarily invoked on every request. e.g. you want a different error-handler for requests under `/api/*` as opposed to `/user-visible-HTML-pages/*`
- Speaking generally again (so not being specific to ASP.NET Core), a common technique for composing pipelines in any modern language that supports first-class functions and/or closures is to *dynamcially compose* them at runtime during an initialization phase. As a concrete example, let's look at what a *statically* composed (as opposed to dynamically composed) pipeline of functions would look like:

  ```
  // Implements the example Unix shell pipeline from Bell Labs' video:
  function myPipeline( sentence ) {

       return unique( sort( lowercase( makewords( sentence ) ) ) );
  }
  ```

  Now, to convert that `myPipeline` to use dynamic composition, those hard-coded functions need to be function-pointers, and their output still needs to be passed as input to the next function; to do this, modern libraries/frameworks will have you use a separate "builder" API/configuration-interface for composing the pipeline, so if we represented the above `myPipeline` using something like ASP.NET Core's `Configure()`, it would be something like this:

  ```
  function buildPipeline( builder )
  {
       return builder
           .use( makewords )
           .use( lowercase )
           .use( sort )
           .use( unique )
           .build();
  }
  ```

  The `builder.Use()` function would accept a `function` as a parameter and internally do *something like this*:

  ```
  function builder::use( func ) {
       this.steps.add( func );
       return this;
  }

  function builder::build() {
       return function( input ) {
           let prevOutput = input;
           foreach( const func of this.steps ) {
               prevOutput = func( prevOutput );
           }
           retunr prevOutput;
       }
  }
  ```

  Notice that the `build()` function *returns a closure* (the `return function( input ) { ... }`), which captures its internal `steps`, which *is* the built pipeline. To "run" the pipeline you just need to invoke the returned `function( input ) {...}` and receive the result.
- With that exposition out the way.... it then follows that when ASP.NET Core uses the term "alternative pipeline" means that *there exists* another HTTP request+response processing pipeline which will be used to try to complete a HTTP request which failed.
- This is indeed the case: when you call `.UseExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder, ...)`, [this is what happens](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/240377059ec25b4d9d86d4188a26722e55edc5a1/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerExtensions.cs#L57)

  - <sub>(Note that my sequence-of-events below does not correspond exactly to the sequence of instructions inside `UseExceptionHandler`)</sub>:

  1. The `UseExceptionHandler` method takes your current (still-being-composed) pipeline and adds a new middleware step to it: `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` ([actually, it's `ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/240377059ec25b4d9d86d4188a26722e55edc5a1/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.cs)).

     - So when an exception is thrown inside the pipeline while it's processing a request, it will be caught and presumably logged.
  2. But `UseExceptionHandler` *also* calls `app.New()` to create a *brand new* pipeline from scratch, which is initially empty - then it passes the new builder for this new pipeline back to the `Action<IApplicationBuilder> configure` callback so that the application-code can then add more middleware steps to it, if desired (presumably to show a user-friendly error message, etc).
  3. After the `configure` callback returns, `UseExceptionHandler` calls `.Build()` on that pipeline-builder (so now it's a *baked*/composed pipeline that's ready to handle requests), and then stores that pipeline in its `ExceptionHandler` field/property.
  4. So at runtime, when `ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl` catches an exception, it aborts the rest of the current pipeline and instead passes the current HTTP request details to that `ExceptionHandler` property - which contains an entire separate pipeline, which then (hopefully!) runs to completion to build a response for the end-user/remote-client.

     - [This can be seen inside the `ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.Invoke` method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/240377059ec25b4d9d86d4188a26722e55edc5a1/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.cs#L89C19-L89C19), where it does `return this.HandleException(context, edi);`.
  5. Note that the design of `UseExceptionHandler` means it *won't* handle a second exception thrown in the secondary pipeline - for that reason, if you expect your exception-handling-pipeline to fail, you'll want to add *another* call to `UseExceptionHandler` inside its `configure` callback (though you probably shouldn't need to do this, as exception-handling code *should not* raise exceptions of its own...)

Answer (score 1):

You can see what the exception handler middleware does in the source: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/240377059ec25b4d9d86d4188a26722e55edc5a1/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.cs#L111.

What I think they are referring to is that the middleware will reset the current HTTP context and run a new request through the middleware pipeline.
At least that is if you provide the ExceptionHandlingPath to it.