# How do you access appsettings.json from console app

Tags: c#, console-application, appsettings, .net-7.0

I've configured the appsettings.json file and load it in the Main but am unable to access the values; it always returns null.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "smdbapi_url": "https://localhost:7084/Database?data="
}
```

**Main**

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
    .Build();

var services = new ServiceCollection();

ConfigureServices(services);
services
    .AddSingleton<Executor, Executor>()
    .BuildServiceProvider()
    .GetService<Executor>()
    .AppStart(config, args);
```

**Executor**

```
public void AppStart(IConfiguration config, string[] args)
{
    _config = config;

    _args = args;

    string? smdbapi_url = _config.GetValue<string>("smdbapi_url");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the JSON file is being copied to your build folder? What happens if you do this instead? `.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read AppSettings values from a .json file in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-a-json-file-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

DavidG's comment prompting me to check the build folder solved the issue.  I'm accustomed to not having to check the build property of the appsettings.json file. So, pro tip :-), if you have to add the file you have to set it's build properties.   Thanks, David...