# Why I am getting error trying to access app settings?

Tags: c#, jwt, .net-8.0, secret-key

When trying to run my API I am getting this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')
> at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
> at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
> at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\Users\ramit\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Photos\HSPA2024\WebAPI\Program.cs:line 24

In my program.cs I have the below code in lines 23,24:

```
var secretKey = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Key").Value;
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
```

and in appsettings:

```
"AppSettings": {
"Key": "this is my top secret, try to add more for it to work correctly"}
```

What is the error suggests? What is (Parameter 's')?

Comment: Please add tags of language and framework

Comment: When you debug this, can you tell us what the actual value `secretKey` is?

Comment: `key` is a value, not a section. As the error says, the value you passed to `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` is null. That means that `builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Key").Value` returned `null`.

Comment: how it is null and in my appsettings I have a value for key?

Comment: @taleenwahdan Maybe your AppSettings:Key value is null or emtpy in the other settings
as like as appsettings.Development, or UserSecret

please check them

Comment: put entire appsettings.json file. The code you posted is correct. The reason of the error you encountered, must be somewhere else.

Comment: as @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned, you want to read a value (identified by a key), but you call `GetSection`. Instead you need to call `GetValue`. Probably this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-a-json-file-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might sound embarrassing but I was putting the AppSettings in the wrong file. I put that in launchsettings.json instead of appsettings.json