# How to use ConfigurationBinder in Configure method of startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

*asp.net mvc 6 beta5*

I've tried to use config.json to activate\disactive logging

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
         {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            DBContext.ConnectionString = Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString");
        }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("AppSettings"));
        }

// Configure is called after ConfigureServices is called.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
        {
            // that line cause NullReferenceException  
            AppSettings settings = ConfigurationBinder.Bind<AppSettings>(Configuration);  
             if (settings.Log.IsActive)
             {
              ................
        }
```

Example from [ASP.NET 5 (vNext) - Getting a Configuration Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263681/asp-net-5-vnext-getting-a-configuration-setting)  and http://perezgb.com/2015/07/04/aspnet-5-typed-settings-with-the-configurationbinder/
Is there another way to get an instance of the AppSettings in the "configure" method? I need typed object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every service configured in `ConfigureServices` can be injected in the `Configure` method by the runtime:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IOptions<AppSettings> options)
{
    // access options.Options here
}
```

This is a bit cleaner solution than accessing the `ServiceProvider` directly.

Answer (score 5):

you can get it like this using service locator:

```
IOptions<AppSettings> settings = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<AppSettings>>();
if (settings.Options.whatever)
  {
     ...
  }
```

I noticed that if you create a new project with the final release of VS 2015 the project template doesn't include AppSettings as the previous project template did, not sure why.