# ASP.NET 5 - Access to Dependency Container in Startup.Configure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to access my `Options` instance which is added as singleton in `ConfigureServices`. Here is my code:

```
public class Startup
{
    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton((serviceProvider) => ConfigurationBinder.Bind<Options>(Configuration));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var root = ""; // I want to access my Options instance to get root from it
        var fileServerOptions = new FileServerOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(root)
        };
        app.UseFileServer(fileServerOptions);
    }
}
```

My question is how to access instance of `Options` in `Configure` method to set root variable.

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541944/how-to-use-configurationbinder-in-configure-method-of-startup-cs

Comment: Thanks. That was my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [How to use ConfigurationBinder in Configure method of startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541944), the runtime can inject the options directly into the `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Options options)
{
    // do something with options
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to Joe Audette's comment this is the solution:

```
var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<Options>();
```