# How do I get the contents of a JSON file I added in the StartUp method to use it in one of my actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, configuration

This is a continuation from [How do I access Configuration in any class in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231951/how-do-i-access-configuration-in-any-class-in-asp-net-core)

I added a singleton for IConfiguration and I inject it into my Controller.

Now how do I get the contents of a JSON file I added in the StartUp method to use it in one of my actions?

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the Options Pattern from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#using-options-and-configuration-objects