# IOptionsSnapshot Dependency Injection from Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

i have a .net core 2.0 application which has an appsettings.json file which holds the configuration for the service.

In my startup script i added this code:

```
services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration"));
```

Now the settings binded. And i could access the Configuration from any controller, for example like this:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private AppConfiguration _mySettings;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor binds the AppConfiguration
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="settings"></param>
        public HomeController(IOptionsSnapshot<AppConfiguration> settings)
        {
            _mySettings = settings.Value;
            this.IsOnline = _mySettings.MQTTSettings.Active && _mySettings.MicroserviceID != 0;
        }
    }
```

Now there is my question. I also would like to use the IOptionsSnapshot from normal classes which aren't extend the abstract Controller Class. For example like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(IOptionsSnapshot<AppConfiguration> optionsSnapshot)
    {
           //DO SOME STUFF WITH THE Snapshot
    }
}
```

The Problem is, that i have to pass the IOptionsSnapshot to the Testclass when i try to create an object from it.

```
TestClass t = new TestClass(NEEDS AN IOptionsSnapsot Object);
```

So how can i get the IOptionsSnapshot or is there any other possibility to put it into the TestClass? How could i access it in this case?

For example at the Startup Routine i don't have any Controller Call before, so i need the IOptionsSnapshot first in the Class.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use DI to inject IConfiguration to your class, then get setting from IConfiguration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231951/how-do-i-access-configuration-in-any-class-in-asp-net-core  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?tabs=basicconfiguration

Comment: You have to use IoC/DI **all the way**. Basically means, never use `new` except for models (which should not have any dependencies

Comment: @itikhomi: There is no reason to inject IConfiguration, the options snapshot is already registered with he IoC container and gets resolved as it should.

Answer (score 3):

You are simply not supposed to create service classes manually using `new`. The point about dependency injection is to *not* have the responsibility of having to create types and as such pass the correct dependencies to it. Instead, you are supposed to *ask* for an instance of your type and have the dependency container resolve the dependencies for you.

So wherever you are attempting to do `new TestClass`, you should instead inject a `TestClass` instance. This requires your `TestClass` to be registered with the service collection, and this also requires your consumer of the `TestClass` to be *also* resolved through dependency injection. Basically, everything that are not data classes is supposed to be resolved through dependency injection.

For example, in your `Startup`’s `ConfigureServices` method, you want to register your `TestClass` as a service:

```
services.AddTransient<TestClass>();
```

Then, in your controller, you might want to use the `TestClass`, so you inject it:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly TestClass _testClass;

    public HomeController(TestClass testClass)
    {
        _testClass = testClass;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = _testClass.DoSomething();
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

And because `TestClass` is resolved through dependency injection, it can have dependencies as well that will be resolved automatically:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly IOptionsSnapshot<AppConfiguration> _options;

    public TestClass(IOptionsSnapshot<AppConfiguration> optionsSnapshot)
    {
        _options = optionsSnapshot;
    }

    public SomeViewModel DoSomething()
    {
        // access the options
        var active = _options.Value.MQTTSettings.Active;

        // it’s fine to actively create *data* objects
        return new SomeViewModel()
        {
            IsActive = active,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: what is if i'm using for example entity framework and want to change by the runtime the database-connection-string. Sometimes i have to get a object for example from databasecontext db = new databasecontext() so if i can not create a object of this, how should i handle it

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler By default, the EF Core context options that are passed to the `AddDbContext()` call are registered as scoped dependencies (just like the context itself). So if your configuration source and the configuration action supports changing configuration at runtime, then the new configuration should be picked up for the next request automatically. You generally should _not_ create a database context yourself, use DI for that instead. – If you are having troubles with that, feel free to open up a new question for that.