# Load Custom ConfigSection in ASP.NET Core Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We have a new **ASP.NET Core 2.0** application but we need to use a .NET Framework 4.6.1 library that requires access to a Custom ConfigSection defined in a Web.config (or similar). Initial attempts lead to errors indicating the internal component cannot load/find the section. This works fine in non-core applications and we are hoping there is a way to make this work in Core.

Here is a sample of how it's registered in the config file.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="data-connector" type="Connector.Configuration.ConnectorConfigSection, Connector" />
</configSections>
```

If it helps, the below code is used by the component to load it's config section.

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads an instance of a specified configuration section or a default instance if one was not found
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The Configuration Section type to be loaded</typeparam>
/// <param name="sectionName">The name/path of the section to be loaded as seen in the config file</param>
public static T GetSectionInstance<T>(string sectionName) where T : ConfigurationSection
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sectionName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("sectionName");

    var instance = (ConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName);

    return (instance == null || !typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(instance.GetType()))
            ? Activator.CreateInstance<T>()
            : instance as T;
}
```

We can ask the component owner to make changes to their load process but we cannot make this a native-Core component.

Is there a work-around to ensure web.config section can still be supported?

Comment: Do you have access to the settings file source code (usually generated by VS)? If yes, maybe you can port it to .NET Core? The loading logic should be pretty basic right?

Comment: Sorry Meikel, this is not an option for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET Core 2.0 on .NET Framework, then you'll need to use app.config instead of web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You can add configuration or it's section using DI container in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` and inject it to controller or service witch will use your library.

Comment: We are happy to do this but we don't understand how to do this. Can you provide a sample?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection Should help you getting started with DI in .Net Core

Comment: Please, read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231951/how-do-i-access-configuration-in-any-class-in-asp-net-core
All you need after what. is to pass your configuration to your library in class where it was injected and where you use it.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the OP's (perfectly reasonable) question, at least not without an example. I have read the link you posted (in a comment), but it does not seem to specifically cover what is necessary to pull this off. Please add the details of how to make this work (if known) *in the answer itself*. DI would be the answer *if the component vendor made it possible to do so*, but if the component is expecting to get settings out of a custom config section this probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just create an App.config like below. Working in ASP.NET Core.
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="EmailConfig" type="MyApp.Handler,MyApp">
  </configSections>
  <EmailConfig to = "to@test.com" from="from@test.com"
    subject="test" body ="" />
</configuration>
```