# Accessing appsettings.json from different projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .Net Core 2.1 to create a Web API. My solution contains different projects and there is one appsettings.json file in the main/startup project.
I want to read appsettings from different projects. For that I have created a class in a Common project referenced to every other projects.

```
namespace Common
{
    public sealed class ApplicationSettings
    {
        public ApplicationSettings(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            InitSettings(configuration);
        }

        public string CloudStorageConnectionString { get; private set; }

        private void InitSettings(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            CloudStorageConnectionString = configuration["CloudStorageAccountConnection"];
        }
    }
}
```

Then I try to configure this in the Startup class in the startup project-

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    //I can read the AppSettings values here via Configuration..

    var settings = new ApplicationSettings(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton(settings);
}
```

Finally using it-

```
public class ToolService : IToolService
{
    private DataContext _dataContext = null;
    private readonly Common.ApplicationSettings _settings;
    public ToolService()
    {
        _dataContext = new DataContext();
    }

    public ToolService(Common.ApplicationSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings; //settings is null here
    }

    public ToolDetailModel ReadToolDetail(int toolDetailID)
    {
        ToolDetailModel toolDetailModel = null;
        try
        {
            var cloudConnection = _settings.CloudConnectionString; //settings is null here      
            //...
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return toolDetailModel;
    }
}
```

This is how I am calling the above function, again in my API controller which is in the main startup project-

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        IToolService _toolService = new ToolService();
        _toolService.ReadToolDetail(1);
        //...
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

The `AppSettings` object is null when I am trying to use them in a different project by passing them as parameter (using Dependency Injection as shown above).

Am I doing it wrong? Please let me know if I can add more details.

Comment: What type of project is `a different project`? Console, ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @SimplyGed Class library project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined two constructors for `ToolService` and currently you are calling the wrong constructor in your other project. You should modify it so you have only one constructor:

```
public ToolService(Common.ApplicationSettings settings)
{
    _dataContext = new DataContext();
    _settings = settings; //settings is null here
}
```

If you want your class library to use dependency injection then you need to register it with the `services` collection e.g.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    //I can read the AppSettings values here via Configuration..

    var settings = new ApplicationSettings(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton(settings);

    // use whatever lifetime you prefer
    services.AddScoped<ToolService>();
}
```

Now when you try to call `new ToolService()` it will complain saying you need to provide the `ApplicationSettings` parameter.
The problem is you cannot use `new ToolService()` if you are using dependency injection. You need to ask the dependency injector to create the class for you. In the case of ASP.NET Core, that is the `IServiceProvider` interface.

You don't show where you are creating the `ToolService` class. If it is in a class that is registered in `ConfigureServices` then you can just pass the `ToolService` as a constructor parameter and the dependency injector will resolve the reference for you, including the `ApplicationSettings` parameter that the `ToolService` class wants e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(ToolService toolService)
    {
        _toolService = toolService;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        _toolService.ReadToolDetail(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my post. Basically I am instantiating the `ToolService` in my API Controller class. I can't inject `ToolService` to my API controller class I believe? Can you please suggest a better approach? Thanks again.

Comment: You certainly can inject the `ToolService` into an API controller :-). As long as you have registered the `ToolService` in the `ConfigureServices` method you can inject it into any other class that has been registered with the `IServiceCollection` (NOTE: Controllers are automatically registered by the framework)

Comment: So whenever I have to access `MyMethod()` I have to instantiate `MyClass` by passing `ToolService` reference?

Comment: If you want to create the class manually i.e. using `new MyClass(..)` then yes.

Comment: That might be turn out complicated at some time later. Is there a simpler way to just access the app settings in all my projects? What I understand, as a practice no other projects should have direct access to appsettings.json except the startup project. Is that so?

Comment: You need to use Dependency Injection to safely share the appsettings in other classes. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39231951/2309376) for more details. And, yes. You should only configure the loading of `appsettings.json` in the `Startup` class. Every other class should use the `IConfiguration` interface to access the settings, or a class that holds the settings - which is what you have in your case e.g. ApplicationSettings.
You may also want to read up on [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)