# How to read appsetting.json from any class blazor serverside

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, appsettings

i know how to acess to appsetting.json fron razor component but how from any class in a blazor serverside project?

from razor component i simply inject:

@inject IConfiguration _config

and access all that i need like :
_config.GetConnectionString("default")

but how can do the same from any class?
when i try to do

IConfiguration _config;

it says when i want to reach data that _config is null or is an unassigned local variable depands where i write the variable.

Comment: Did you have declared registration of iconfiguration in code, just like ```services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);```

Comment: you can reference [How do I access Configuration in any class in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39232929/15073910)

Comment: @KenTsu thanks i add the service but how can i access from a class?
and for the link seems its not for blazor serverside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i understood how it work so i can answer my question myself

in fact, you just have to add a constructor in your class with Iconfiguration as argumentand you can use it and call your data stored in your app setteing:

```
    public class MyClass 
{
    public MyClass (IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }


    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    


    void MyMethod(){
            .....
           }
}
```

You can use it after in your method:

```
string myCon = _config.GetConnectionString("Default");
```

Comment: Wow, so this means you can't access configurations directly in blazor? It seems your solution was to basically add the configs to your data object, which is disappointing because configuration data should be a cross-cutting possibility.

Answer (score 11):

- first, you should create custom config model

```
    public class PositionOptions
    {
        public const string Position = "Position";

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

- then, register config model in startup.cs

```
services.Configure<PositionOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position));
```

- don not forget appsetting.json

```
 "Position": {
    "Title": "Editor",
    "Name": "Joe Smith"
  }
```

- at last, inject ioptions in the index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using WebApplication.Model
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@inject IOptions<PositionOptions> _options
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<h1>@_options.Value.Title</h1>
<h1>@_options.Value.Name</h1>

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?"/>
```

Comment: 1)thanks for your answer @Ken Tsu .... 2)you are wrong, you didn't need to move appsetting for make it work like you said in a razor component, you have simply to inject on your page and it work :-) .... 3)You didn't understand my question, i said that i need to get data from a class NOT a page or razor component .... 4) still looking for a solution if anyone have

Comment: @KhalidAb updated, you can reference  [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: very strange that it is very simple to get data from appsetting to razor component and NOT to class ... i think it must be easier way to get it than create an other class or custom config model... thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @KhalidAb Could you give me more infos?

Answer (score 7):

This is just a complement to @khalidAb and @KenTsu answers perhaps you find it useful. I usually work this way. Like KenTsu mentioned, it is just an implementation of Options pattern, he did it for a Blazor component, this is just for any class.

**appSettings.json**

```
"PositionOptions": {
    "Title": "Editor",
    "Name": "Joe Smith"
}
```

**Model**

```
public class PositionOptions
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.Configure<PositionOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(PositionOptions)));
```

**Any class**

```
public class AnyClass {
    private readonly PositionOptions _positionOptions;

    public MyClass(IOptions<PositionOptions> positionOptions)
    {
        _positionOptions = positionOptions.Value;
    }

    public Get()
    {
        string title = _positionOptions.Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can class PositionOptions use a DI class that also using PositionOptions ?

Comment: Not sure but what would you do that?