# Visual Studio 2022 System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I know this is still in preview, but I just want to make sure I am not doing anything wrong as I have done things  like this in the past.  I have my Environment variables set in properties:
[image]

And I am trying to set up my tests:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    var test = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
    // test enumerates all the Env variables, don't see it there
    var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONNECTION_STRING");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString)) // so this is obviously null
        throw new ArgumentNullException("CONNECTION_STRING");
    _ConnectionString = connectionString;
}
```

As you can see by my comments, the environment variables are not found/loaded.

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Are you debugging or running tests?

Comment: Debugging the tests

Comment: Which project did you set the variables on? The test project? Or the web app?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using Visual Studio 2022 because you are using .NET 6 and the minimal host (i.e., no `Startup.cs`)?

The general preference is not to store information in the Environment Variables given that this information is often uploaded to GitHub and can be trawled and used against you.

For a local development secret, the preference is to store these using the `secrets.json` file. There is information on how to do this at [Safe Storage of Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows), as well as details on accessing Configuration files at [Accessing Configuration File Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231951/how-do-i-access-configuration-in-any-class-in-asp-net-core).

For the TL;DR: Crowd the steps below might help (this is what I did in my Blazor app with .NET 6):

1. In Visual Studio 2022, right click on the project in question and select 'Manage User Secrets'.  This will create a local `secrets.json` file and open it.  It will also add a GUID in your project tile for `UserSecretsId`.
2. Create your secrets as JSON key value pairs in this file as you would for environment variables.
3. Go to 'Connected Services' in your project and configure the `Secrets.json` service.
4. Add the 'User Secrets' to your configuration file; this will depend on exactly where this is happening.
5. Inject the `IConfiguration` into your controller and save this to a field.
6. Call the data you want using:

   ```
   {yourConfigurationFieldName}.GetValue<string>({yourJsonKey})
   ```

Comment: This is excellent, but I am not using a controller, this is a test project - I will look into that, but if you already know, that would be great-  thank you!

Comment: This was simple to set up in tests: https://patrickhuber.github.io/2017/07/26/avoid-secrets-in-dot-net-core-tests.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: @Kuranes I agree. The question is HOW to get the environment variables. Based on this ms docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-ports-via-the-aspnetcore_urls-environment-variable

Answer (score 11):

In Visual Studio 2022, you can access environment variables in development by modifying the following section of launchSettings.json file.

"environmentVariables": {
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
"VaultUri": "https://xxx.vault.azure.net/",
"AZURE_USERNAME": "xxx@user.com"
}

where VaultUri is the name of your environment variable.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with test projects.