# How to access my configuration in any class in a .NET Azure Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have different projects, in some of them it is fairly simple to access configuration items, in others it's not - and I have difficulties finding out why. All are .NET 6 projects.

Note I have checked out [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231951/how-do-i-access-configuration-in-any-class-in-asp-net-core) that looked similar as well as [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but neither seems to work. Kindly read through my question before flagging it as duplicate.

**How it works in a Function App:**

In my `Startup.cs` file I have this:

```
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        [...]
        // This is not really relevant but you see how I access configuration settings
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyClient", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(C.Configuration.GetValue<string>("BaseAddress"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization",  $"Bearer {C.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiToken")}");  
        });
        [...]
    }

    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true)
            .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    }
```

Also, I have a static class `C` that holds all kinds of constants - as well as the configuration. I post the relevant part as a screenshot on purpose, you'll understand why.
[image: Function app C.cs]

So far, so good - in any place of the whole Function App project I can access any configuration setting by using `C.Configuration.GetValue<Type>("setting")`.

**How it does not work in an App Service**

Now I have an App Service - and all I want is the exactly same functionality. However, it does not work, `Configuration` is null. The relevant part of `C.cs` looks exactly the same:
[image: App service C.cs]
You'll notice, however, that in one case the line `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` is greyed out by VS which means it is considered obsolete, while this is not the case in the Function App `C.cs`.

I assumed this must have something to do with the startup configuration or dependency injection, so I tried to configure it the same way as in the Function App. This is what I added to my `Program.cs` which obviously is the equivalent to `Startup.cs` in a Function App:

```
builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
    
    ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
```

The configuration is even added as a DI Singleton:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
```

Now you probably ask why I want to have the configuration in that C class when it's there as an injectable singleton. From what I understand the singleton is injected in my Controller classes - but I have lots of other classes that need to get values from the configuration. I am perfectly aware that I could pass down the configuration object to all dependent classes as a parameter in the constructor. This concept of DI is absolutely legit, but I consider it a bit over the top when it comes to configuration items. Just calling

```
`C.Configuration.GetValue<Type>("setting")`
```

anywhere in the code seems more convenient and logical to me. Note that C is not a singleton class but rather a static class - and since this works in the Function App, I had hoped it would work in the App service project as well.

Anyone can point me in the right direction? Happy to share more code snippets if required.

Comment: It is not obsolete, it's just that the import (use) is already known. As for why the squiggly green line is there: hover your mouse over it and read the text the IDE gives you. And for accessing configuration through a singleton: look into the IOptions pattern.

Comment: Are you setting `C.Configuration` anywhere?   It looks like you're correctly setting up `IConfiguration` for dependency injection, but I don't see anywhere that you're actually taking the configuration that you've assembled it and assigning it to your static config.

Answer (score 1):

Are you ever actually calling `C.Configuration = XXX` anywhere?   I see in your code screenshots that you're using the configuration builder to setup `IConfiguration` for dependency injection, but nowhere are you assigning it to your static `C.Configuration` property.

Maybe it's something as simple as

```cs
C.Configuration = builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

Comment: Thanks for asking, I thought I posted an answer to my question but obviously I did not. This is basically what I ended up doing. C was originally a static class as you can see above so this would not work. Thus, I converted it to an old fashioned Singleton class providing its instance as `C.Instance`. In the `Program.cs` file I basically do now what you suggested, and now I can access the configuration from the Singleton as `C.Instance.Configuration`. Still, I confused why it works in the Function App and not in the App Service, I just don't see the difference.

Answer (score -3):

These are some OAuth request samples. I think this will help you to get some idea about the OAuth request.

```
 public async Task<string> SynchEntitiesOAuthGET(SynchParameterModel model)
        {
            string response = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var access_token = ÒAuthConnector.GetOAuthToken(_eagleSettings.OAuthTokenIssuerURL, _eagleSettings.OAuthClientId, _eagleSettings.OAuthClientSecret, _eagleSettings.OAuthScope);

                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);
                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, model.APIEndPoint);
                    responseMessage =await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                }

                response =await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                ExceptionWeb(ex, model.RecordType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionSystem(ex, model.RecordType);
            }

            return response;
        }
        public async Task<string> SynchEntitiesOAuthPOST(SynchParameterModel model)
        {
            string response = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var access_token = ÒAuthConnector.GetOAuthToken(_eagleSettings.OAuthTokenIssuerURL, _eagleSettings.OAuthClientId, _eagleSettings.OAuthClientSecret, _eagleSettings.OAuthScope);

                var bodyJson = model.RequestBody;// JsonSerializer.Serialize(model.RequestBody);
                var stringContent = new StringContent(bodyJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);
                    responseMessage =await httpClient.PostAsync(model.APIEndPoint, stringContent);
                }

                response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                ExceptionWeb(ex, model.RecordType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionSystem(ex, model.RecordType);
            }

            return response;
        }

        public string SynchEntitiesBasicAuthenticationPOST(SynchParameterModel model)
        {
            var response = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                string username = _eagleSettings.WebServiceUser;
                string password = _eagleSettings.WebServicePassword;

                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(model.APIEndPoint);
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentType = "application/json";
                req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
                req.Timeout = int.MaxValue;

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = model.RequestBody;
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                }

                HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
                {
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                ExceptionWeb(ex, model.RecordType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionSystem(ex, model.RecordType);
            }

            return response;
        }

        public string SynchEntitiesBasicAuthenticationGET(SynchParameterModel model)
        {
            string response = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                string username = _eagleSettings.WebServiceUser;
                string password = _eagleSettings.WebServicePassword;

                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(model.APIEndPoint);
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
                req.Timeout = int.MaxValue;

                HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
                {
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                ExceptionWeb(ex, model.RecordType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionSystem(ex, model.RecordType);
            }

            return response;
        }
```

SynchParameterModel class

```
 public partial class SynchParameterModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set Record type for sync entity
        /// </summary>
        public string RecordType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set API end point for get record
        /// </summary>
        public string APIEndPoint { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set from sync date time
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime FromDateTime { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set to sync date time
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime ToDateTime { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set to request type. this should be GET or POST
        /// </summary>
        public string RequestType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set to request body. this should POST request
        /// </summary>
        public string RequestBody { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm completely stupid but I cannot see how this would even remotely answer my question... Are you sure you posted to the right question?